# Client socket not communicating with handler in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm learning about sockets in Python and have been playing around with the famous echo server. I'm trying to use the `asyncore` library for asynchronous IO, but I'm getting this weird behavior from the client socket.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import socket
import asyncore

class Handler(asyncore.dispatcher):
    '''
    Class to handle connected clients and send them messages.
    '''
    def __init__(self, sock, server):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, sock)
        self.server = server
        self.buffer = 'Connection accepted'

    def writable(self):
        return len(self.buffer) > 0

    def handle_read(self):
        '''
        Read from the buffer.
        '''
        data = self.recv(2)

        if not data:
            raise RuntimeError('Lost connection to client.')

        print 'Handler received: %s' % data

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)

        print 'sent %d bytes' % sent
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(1)

    def handle_accept(self):
        self.client, _ = self.accept()
        self.handler = Handler(client, self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 5655

    server = Server('', port)
    client = socket.socket()
    client.connect(('localhost', port))

    asyncore.loop(0.1, count=5)

    client.send('hi')
    print 'Client received: %s' % client.recv(19)

    asyncore.loop(1, count=1)
```

When I try to connect a client socket to the server, it can't communicate at all with the handler. Here's what happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
    print 'Client received: %s' % server.client.recv(19)
socket.error: [Errno 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

However, if I use the client socket returned by the server's `accept` method instead of the original client socket, it works as expected:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 5655

    server = Server('', port)
    client = socket.socket()
    client.connect(('localhost', port))

    asyncore.loop(0.1, count=5)

    server.client.send('hi')
    print 'Client received: %s' % server.client.recv(19)

    asyncore.loop(1, count=1)
```

Output:

```
sent 19 bytes
Client received: Connection accepted
Handler received: hi
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it the expected behavior? If the latter is true, I really need to improve my understanding of sockets.

Comment: Your code works. Are you calling `client.setblocking(False)` anywhere?

Comment: @Blender I'm not. I tried to call `setblocking(False)` and `setblocking(True)`, nothing changed.

Comment: And you get this error when running the *exact* code in your first code block?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I posted the first code block wrong. Using `client.recv(19)` instead of `server.client.recv(19)` gave the error.